# Matplotlib: Subplot Axis Ticks and MajorLocator

Tags: datetime, matplotlib, subplot

I am dynamically creating several subplots based on underlying data.  The xaxis are datetime varying in the number of hours for each subplot.  When I set the final axes major locator it affects all the locators for all the axes.  For example is the if the final subplot time range is 00:00 to 06:00 and the first subplot range was 00:00 to 13:00 maplotlib only puts labels on the fist subplot ranging from 00:00 to 06:00.

If I let it autolocate it places a sufficient number of labels, but the time interval varies.  It might place a tick at 06:28, when I want the ticks to fall on the hour.

Below is the code segment:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fw, fh))
plt.suptitle(title, horizontalalignment = 'left', x= 0.12, y=0.955, fontsize = 14, name = 'Arial')

f = '#4C709D'
m = 'o'
a = 0.5
ms = 6
yfnt = 10

if len(x1)>0:
    position+=1
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((axis,1), (position, 0))
    ax1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    a=ax1.scatter(x1, y1, s = ms, color = f, marker = m, alpha=0.5)
    r=ax1.scatter(x1, z1, s = 2, color='black', marker= m, alpha=0.5, label='15min Rolling Avg')

    ax1.set_xlim(min(x1), max(x1))
    ax1.set_ylim(-0.01, max(y1)+1)

    ax1.set_ylabel('[VOC] (ppm)', fontsize = yfnt)

    for label in ax1.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    for label in ax1.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
    ax1.grid(b=True, axis='both', which ='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, alpha = 0.10)


if len(x2) > 0:
    position+=1
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((axis, 1), (position, 0))
    ax2.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    a=ax2.scatter(x2, y2, s = ms, color = f, marker = m, alpha=0.5)
    r=ax2.scatter(x2, z2, s = 2, color='black', marker= m, alpha=0.5, label='15min Rolling Avg')

    ax2.set_ylim(-0.01, max(y2)+1)
    ax2.set_xlim(min(x2), max(x2))
    ax2.set_ylabel('% LEL', fontsize = yfnt)

    for label in ax2.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    for label in ax2.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
    ax2.grid(b=True, axis='both', which ='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, alpha = 0.10)


if len(x3) > 0:
    position+=1
    ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((axis, 1), (position, 0))
    ax3.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    a=ax3.scatter(x3, y3, s = ms, color = f, marker = m, alpha=0.5)
    r=ax3.scatter(x3, z3, s = 2, color='black', marker= m, alpha=0.5, label = '15min Rolling Avg')

    ax3.set_ylim(-0.01, max(y3)+5)
    ax3.set_xlim(min(x3), max(x3))
    ax3.set_ylabel('[Carbon Dioxide] (ppm)', fontsize = yfnt)

    for label in ax3.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    for label in ax3.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    ax3.set_xticklabels(ax3.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
    ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
    ax3.grid(b=True, axis='both', which ='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, alpha = 0.10)


if len(x4) > 0:
    position+=1
    ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((axis, 1), (position, 0))
    ax4.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
    a=ax4.scatter(x4, y4, s = ms, color = f, marker = m, alpha= 0.5)
    r=ax4.scatter(x4, z4, s = 2, color='black', marker= m, alpha=0.5, label='15min Rolling Avg')

    ax4.set_ylim(-0.01, max(y4)+1)
    ax4.set_xlim(min(x4), max(x4))
    ax4.set_ylabel('[Oxygen] (%)', fontsize = yfnt)

    for label in ax4.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    for label in ax4.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    ax4.set_xticklabels(ax4.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
    ax4.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
    ax4.grid(b=True, axis='both', which ='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, alpha = 0.10)

if len(x5) > 0:
    position+=1
    ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((axis, 1), (position, 0))
    ax5.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

    a = ax5.scatter(x5, y5, color=f, s=ms, marker=m, alpha=0.5)
    r = ax5.scatter(x5, z5, s = 2, color='black', marker= m, alpha=0.5, label='15min Rolling Avg')

    ax5.set_ylim(-0.01, max(y5)+1)
    ax5.set_xlim(min(x5), max(x5))
    ax5.set_ylabel('[Methane] (ppm)', fontsize = yfnt)

    for label in ax5.get_yticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    for label in ax5.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_fontsize(9)

    ax5.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    ax5.set_xticklabels(ax5.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=45)
    ax5.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
    ax5.grid(b=True, axis='both', which ='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1, alpha = 0.10)
```

Comment: Try this for your duplicated `if` statements: put the sets of `(ax, y, z, labels)`etc into a list of tuples and iterate over the tuples: `for (ax, y, z, labels) in list_axes: if len(x) > 0: ...` 

To nice up shared limits, save the smallest and largest xmin, xmax overall, and at the end round them down and up to hours and set the final (and shared) major locators to those limits.